# Provoking Floating Port

Tags: microcontroller, pins, test, floating

I have  a floating pin / port on a micro controller. I want to show that the maximum additional current from this pin is above a certain safty threshold.

Can I somehow provoke the pin to draw current / change potential.

Comment: *"I have a floating pin...the maximum additional current from this pin is above a certain safty threshold."* 1) floating pins cannot conduct additional currents 2) maybe you mean that leaving the pin floating causes additional currents to flow inside the microC ? 3) You might want to have these currents **below** a certain **"safe"** threshold **4) It is ALWAYS a bad idea to have an input floating, YOU MUST either define it as off/pull down/pull up/output.** Only incompetent designers leave inputs floating on CMOS ICs (i.e. almost all digital chips).

Comment: I'm aware of what you say. But I have a board that consumes too much over time and I know how much it has to be at least so I'm trying to proof this could or couldnt be the reason

Comment: Also I didn't develop it, I'm assigned to find the bug..

Comment: Can't you disable the pin via a software update ?

Comment: Software update is done, but how we know it is the bug its just a bug

Comment: If the "consumes too much over time" issue is now gone, you've found it. If not, at least you fixed another potential bug :-)

Comment: consumes too much after say 3 months...

Comment: That is a nasty problem. Would resetting it every month be a workaround option ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the worst consumption from the mcu is when the voltage on floating pin is on middle, but you can check.

You can attach some pot so you can change voltage on it. Or even better some DAC would be nice. That way you can programmatically change voltage. During those swings measure current.

Comment: *I think the worst consumption from the mcu is when the voltage on floating pin is on middle* That is true if only a few gates are affected by the floating pin. But if the floating pin couples to a high frequency clock and the gates start switching at that clock as well it can be a whole different story. It is utterly unpredictable so that's why inputs **must** be defined and must never be left floating.

Comment: Yeah. But I understood he is aware of that but wanted to experimentally see increased consumption.